# SetSecurityInfo returns access denied

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi, ipc

Using C, I'm trying to establish a pipe connection between a process and it's child process, while the child process has a lower mandatory(integrity) level (low, while the parent process is high).

I wrote the following program (it's a simplified version if it), but it fails with: `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5)`

```
INT wmain(IN SIZE_T nArgc, IN PWSTR *pArgv)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityArrtibutes = { 0 };
    HANDLE hPipeRead = NULL;
    HANDLE hPipeWrite = NULL;

    tSecurityArrtibutes.nLength = sizeof(tSecurityArrtibutes);
    tSecurityArrtibutes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    SetSeSecurityNamePrivilege();
    CreatePipe(&hPipeRead, &hPipeWrite, &securityArrtibutes, 0);
    ChangeMandatoryLabelHandle(hPipeRead);
}

VOID ChangeMandatoryLabelHandle(HANDLE hObject)
{
    BOOL bRetval = FALSE;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    PACL ptSacl = NULL;
    BOOL bSaclPresent = FALSE;
    BOOL bSaclDefaulted = FALSE;
    PWSTR pSDDL = NULL;

    SDDL = L"S:(ML;;LW;;;NW)";

    bRetval = ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW(pSDDL, SDDL_REVISION_1, &pSecurityDescriptor, NULL);
    if (FALSE == bRetval)
        ... // Handle failure

    bRetval = GetSecurityDescriptorSacl(pSecurityDescriptor, &bSaclPresent, &ptSacl, &bSaclDefaulted);
    if (FALSE == bRetval)
        ... // Handle failure

    // getting ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0x5)
    dwErr = SetSecurityInfo(hObject, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, ptSacl);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwErr)
        ... // Handle failure

    ... // Cleanup
}
```

I followed https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588(v=vs.85).aspx and the remark that 
`To set the SACL of an object, the caller must have the SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege enabled.` :

```
BOOL SetSeSecurityNamePrivilege()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if(!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY | TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, &hToken)
        return FALSE

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SECURITY_NAME, &luid))
        return FALSE;

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL, (PDWORD)NULL))
        return FALSE;

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}
```

note: I get the same result when I try to execute it with files, with `CreateFile` instead of `CreatePipe`.
In addition if I try to do that with files, and I replace `SetSecurityInfo` with `SetNamedSecurityInfoW`, and give it the full path of the file, it works great.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: As RbMm explains in his answer, changing the security descriptor is not likely to have any effect on whatever problem you are actually trying to solve here.  Once you have convinced yourself of that, I suggest you post another question focusing on your actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes before addressing the cause of your immediate problem.

First and foremost, you do not need to change the security descriptor at all, and doing so is unlikely to help you achieve your ultimate goal.  The security descriptor is only checked when you attempt to open a handle to an object; if you already have a handle, the security descriptor has no effect.  Since you are creating an unnamed pipe, you must be passing the handle, not the pipe name, to the child, so you do not need the *ChangeMandatoryLabelHandle* function at all.

Secondly, the `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege is not needed when setting `LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`.  The mandatory label is logically distinct from the rest of the SACL, and is treated as a special case.

Thirdly, your `"S:(ML;;LW;;;NW)"` is invalid.

I tried to use it in *ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptorW* and got error 1336, *The access control list (ACL) structure is invalid.*  Instead, use`"D:NO_ACCESS_CONTROLS:(ML;;;;;LW)"` or better still use the following code to create a security descriptor with a low label and no DACL:

```
ULONG cb = MAX_SID_SIZE;
PSID LowLabelSid = (PSID)alloca(MAX_SID_SIZE);

ULONG dwError = NOERROR;

if (CreateWellKnownSid(WinLowLabelSid, 0, LowLabelSid, &cb))
{
    PACL Sacl = (PACL)alloca(cb += sizeof(ACL) + sizeof(ACE_HEADER) + sizeof(ACCESS_MASK));

    if (InitializeAcl(Sacl, cb, ACL_REVISION) && 
        AddMandatoryAce(Sacl, ACL_REVISION, 0, 0, LowLabelSid))
    {
        SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
        InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
        SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
        SetSecurityDescriptorSacl(&sd, TRUE, Sacl, FALSE);

        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(sa), &sd, TRUE };

        // todo something here
    }
    else
    {
        dwError = GetLastError();
    }
}
else
{
    dwError = GetLastError();
}
```

But again, you need to understand that there is (almost) never any sense in creating a security descriptor for an unnamed object.  The security descriptor is only checked when opening an object, and (in user mode) you cannot open an object that does not have a name.

(From kernel mode we can open an object by pointer using [*ObOpenObjectByPointer*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550985(v=vs.85).aspx).)

(In older versions of Windows, *CreatePipe* actually created a pipe with a random name, but starting from Windows 7 the pipe really is unnamed, so it cannot be opened with *CreateFile* or any similar method.)

In any case, it is my opinion that using *CreatePipe* in this context was a bad choice.  This function is not well designed and has too few parameters.  There is no option to create a bidirectional pipe or to open the pipe in asynchronous mode.  I think it is better to use *CreateNamedPipeW* and *CreateFileW*.

(Alternatively, from Windows 7 onwards, you can use *ZwCreateNamedPipeFile* and *ZwOpenFile* to create and open an unnamed pipe.)

---

The proximate problem with the code as posted is that [*SetSecurityInfo*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588(v=vs.85).aspx) and [*SetKernelObjectSecurity*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379578(v=vs.85).aspx) return *ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED* when called with the handle returned by [*CreatePipe*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx).  This is because, as described in the documentation for [*LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379573(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Right required to set: **WRITE_OWNER**

Since [*CreatePipe*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx) does not give you the option to select the access rights that the handles are opened with, you have no way of doing this.  If you instead use [*CreateNamedPipe*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150(v=vs.85).aspx) you can set *WRITE_OWNER* in *dwOpenMode*.

However, you should note that if you wish to create an object with a special security descriptor, it is preferable to provide that security descriptor when the object is created.  There is no point in creating the object with a default security descriptor and then changing it; why do in two operations what you can do in one?  In this case, the `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` structure you pass to *CreatePipe* or *CreateNamedPipe* can be used to specify the security descriptor, providing another way of addressing your immediate problem, although as previously mentioned this will not in fact be useful.